# How to loop a function over consecutive cells in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, google-sheets

I have this function and I need to loop the same function on all cells starting from  (c3) until the last row in the column
The function is a statement when searching for a value (c3:lastrow,3) in the order sheet and finding the corresponding value in the sheet. The balance of the item, and if any of the balances are zero, the function is stopped
how can i make loop for this function to other cells?

```
var cell = order.getRange('c3').getValue();
var range =balance.getRange(['b2:b']).getValues();
var rangemap = range.map(function(r){return r[0]});
var cellindex = rangemap.indexOf(cell);
let index = range.findIndex(range => range);
Logger.log(cellindex);
var ratesData = balance.getRange(2,2,balance.getLastRow(),8).getValues();
var searchvalue = cell
var matchRow = ratesData.find(r=>r[0]== searchvalue)
var match = matchRow ? matchRow[7] : ""
console.log(matchRow[7])
if(matchRow[7]==0){
  
  return;
}
```

The function works on cell (c3) only, and I want it to work on the rest of the cells

Comment: i am useing JavaScript for google sheets

Comment: You should probably change this part `order.getRange('c3')` to be dynamic. That is to say, instead of `C3` it should hold a dynamic reference to the row. For example, you could rewrite your function to accept an argument, and then you'd treat that argument as a cell reference: `function myFunction (cellRef) { var cell = order.getRange(cellRef).getValue(); ... }`

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I tried to replace the function (cellRef) { var cell = order.getRange(cellRef).getValue(); ... } with the new one, but it didn't work for me and gave me the same result

Comment: The code you show is not a complete function. Your requirements remain unclear. Please create a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), like this:

```js
function lookupOrderRatesBasedOnBalances() {
  const orders = order.getRange('C3:C').getValues().flat();
  const rates = balance.getRange('B2:I').getValues();
  const balances = rates.map(row => row[0]);
  const result = orders
    .filter(String)
    .map(order => {
      const index = balances.indexOf(order);
      if (index === -1) return null;
      return rates[index][7];
    });
  console.log(result);
}
```